# Can I achieve conditional formatting on a gantt chart?

Tags: 2010, list, gridview, gantt-view

I have created a Gantt view on a list, showing the Gantt chart and several columns.  One of my list columns is a R/Y/G status column. I would like the cell that displays the R/Y/G status to show the color as well as the letter. This doesn't seem like an uncommon scenario, but I have not found anything to help me figure out how to do this on the Gantt view.  I am OK using JQuery or any other viable technique to achieve the end result.

Comment: check this one if it help: http://lindachapman.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-create-gantt-chart-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: Thanks, but it does not help - I already have the gantt and am looking for a way to color-code.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help for a start: http://sharepointbitsandbytes.com/2014/01/sharepoint-2013-quick-edit-javascript-validation/

This describes how to attach a js file to gantt view and how to display messages based on various conditions. RenderField function returns HTML which is then displayed in gantt view. This is very similar to what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; It is not obvious to me upon going to that link how this applies to what I am trying to do. First problem is it seems to be geared toward 2013.